# Remove lines from CSS that contain references to external files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a simple webmail script in php. The content of a message body is retrieved using jQuery which gets the content returned from a php script. For example:

```
$.get("file.php", function(data) { /* Data is the message content */ });
```

From here, I'm then writing the string in data to the document of an iFrame. I want to make sure that the content returned is sanitized and one step to this is removing all references to external files, particularly remote files accessed over http. For example, javascript files or images on a server somewhere. It's important to do this because not only may external scripts try to manipulate my page, external images may be running through a dynamic engine like php and confirming to spammers that my email address is active and able to receive mail, and some images can apparently contain viruses.

The following script can remove a lot of things that may be hazardous:

```
function sanitize(str) {
var html = $(str);
var evil = new     Array("head","base","link","script","img","object","embed","video","audio","iframe");
for (e=0; e<evil.length; e++) { html.find(evil[e]).remove(); }
var result = html.wrap("<div>").parent().html();
return result; }
```

But my question is this: how can I remove a line of css that contains a reference to an external file? For example, if the message body content contained a  tag and inside it was this:

```
background-image: url(http://some/dodgy/server/image.jpg);
```

how would I remove that line from the string?

Comment: What if the CSS is minified? You'll have a whole line of CSS that could get removed needlessly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

has not been tested , but you can try something like

```
str = str.replace(/background\-image:\s*url\(.*\);\s*/ig, "");
```

Comment: Don't forget the background shortcut: `{ background: #000 url('stuff') no-repeat;}` and its variants